# How to get on row click value from different cells?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually i'm trying to set value of a td inside a table in a variable but i'm getting the

> row.getElementByTagName is not a function
>       at selectRow (user.aspx?ID=2:47)

The function is called on tr onclick and has as attribute this

While now i just would show the value of 2nd and 3rd td in an alert.

Here is the script

```
   function selectRow(row) {

        var firstInput = row.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        var user = row.getElementByTagName('td')[1];
        var soft = row.getElementByTagName('td')[2];

        firstInput.checked = !firstInput.checked;
        if (firstInput.checked) {
            alert("AGGIUNGI " + user + " " + soft);
              //document.getElementById('frame').src = "user.aspx?ADDUSER=" + user + "&SOFT=" + soft;
        } else {
              //document.getElementById('frame').src = "user.aspx?DELUSER=" + user + "&SOFT=" + soft;
            alert("ELIMINA " + user + " " + soft);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in jQuery

```
var tds = $(row).find("td");
var user = tds.get(1);
var soft = tds.get(2);
```

Comment: i've got the following as output [object HTMLTableCellElement] [object HTMLTableCellElement]

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If you want to see the text in the TDs you need to change alert("ELIMINA " + user + " " + soft) to alert("ELIMINA " + user.innerText + " " + soft.innerText)